# What is the difference between text and textStorage

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitextview

What is the difference between

```
[self.someTextView text];
```

and

```
[[self.someTextView textStorage] string];
```

When should I use each of them?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you read this? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/CustomTextProcessing/CustomTextProcessing.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the property `text` inherits from `NSString`, `textStorage` inherits from `NSTextStorage`.

The main difference is that `NSTextStorage` is a semiconcrete subclass of NSMutableAttributedString that manages a set of client NSLayoutManager objects, notifying them of any changes to its characters or attributes so that they can relay and redisplay the text as needed. On the other side, `NSString` is a simple string, without attributes.

Use text when you need the string and textStorage when you need all the attributes, in the case the UITextView you're displaying has them.